# Find the minimal non-negative integer $s$ such that: $x \leq s$; $y<s$; $5x + 4y \not\equiv 63$.

Tags: numerical-methods

Find the minimal non-negative integer $s$ such that at least one of the following conditions holds for all non-negative integers $x,y$: $x \leq s$; $y<s$; $5x + 4y \not\equiv 63$.

The answer is 7 but I don't know how to get there, someone please help me

Comment: What have you tried? EG Since you "know" the answer is 7, have you shown that the answer cannot be 6?

Comment: @CalvinLin I have thought that it can be solved in matlab with the fmincon function but I get an error. and it is supposed to be done as if we did not know that the answer is 7

Comment: Consider $(63) \div (4 + 5).$